# вот написал прогу вывода пирамиды,а как сделать ромб?

Tags: php

```
<?php

$height = 5;
for($y=1; $y<=$height; $y++){
    echo str_repeat(' ',$height-$y);
    echo str_repeat('*',$y*2-1)." \n";  
}
```

не могу понять,как правильно сделать...с помошью второго цикла?

Comment: выполняйте тоже самое только в обратном направлении

Answer (score 1):

выполняйте тоже самое только в обратном направлении

```
for($y=$height; $y>0; $y--){
    echo str_repeat(' ',$height-$y);
    echo str_repeat('*',$y*2-1)." \n";  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

вывод по центру

```
$height = 20;
for($y=1; $y<=$height; $y++){
    if ($y % 2 != 0)
    {
        echo str_repeat('&nbsp;',$height-$y);
        echo str_repeat('x',$y)." <br>";  
    }
}

for($y=$height; $y>0; $y--){
    if ($y % 2 != 0)
    {
        echo str_repeat('&nbsp;',$height-$y);
        echo str_repeat('x',$y)." <br>";  
    }
}
```